# Using RedirectAction method to open a new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation in which I need to open a view in new window, in MVC 3.0 without using ACtionLink, We have to use, RedirectAction method. How can we do so?

```
RedirectAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: you want to open new window from controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform client side operations from a controller.

You either need to open the window before hand to the action that results in RedirectToAction.

Or redirect to a page which contains the action in a model and use that to open the window with script.